# What would be the space complexity of an ArrayList of ArrayLists in Java?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, nested-lists, space-complexity

I have a method that returns **`List<List<Integer>>`** in **Java**. What would be the **Space Complexity** of this data structure? Would it be **O(N*M)**, due to nested ArrayLists inside an ArrayList? Or something else?

Comment: What does *N* represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, but may need to refine it a bit.

For the "outer" `ArrayList`, the space complexity is O(n), n being the number of elements in it.
Following your instinct, you should multiply that by the space complexity of the inner `ArrayList`s, which is also their respective size.
However, without any additional information or constraints, you shouldn't assume that the inner and outer `ArrayList`s have the same size, so in a more general sense you'd want to say that if the number of elements in the inner list is m, the total size complexity is O(m * n). If m=n (e.g. each index represents a location, and the the "cell" of the nested array represents the distance between the indexes of the outer and inner map), O(m * n) will indeed be reduced to O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: Couldn't you simplify this to "if there are N elements in total, it is O(N)"?

Comment: @ScottHunter in the total of all the "inner" lists put together? I guess so. But given the structure, I doubt you'll ever count them like that. Although this all boils down to the usecase, and what you actually store in this structure.

Comment: But isn't your O(m*n) = my O(N), regardless of how "close" m & n are?

Comment: @ScottHunter yes, we're ultimately describing the same size - but ultimately m and n should be sizes that mean something in the context of the problem. If the total number of elements "n" means something, that's how you'd describe the space complexity, but if the actual sizes of the inner and outer lists mean something, you'd use them.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList are dynamic data structures and it increases its size by 50% more than the actual size(no of elements). So in real we can say it is taking N+N/2 space.
From the principle of complexity N is the highest degree so O(N).
You have nested lists and inner list determines the space complexity.
n elements in inner list and m inner lists are there then total complexity
O(n*m)